# Extract sound file from api in java or JS

Tags: javascript, java, api, web-applications, media

I am working on a project where we will need some sound files to be imported from this website: https://www.xeno-canto.org/explore/api
Then be implemented in a sound player on a webapplication.

The JSon format is a little bit confusing. Does anyone have a code suggestion/example that might solve this issue?

(First post, I'm new to this forum)

Format of JSON:

```
gen "Rhea"
sp  "americana"
ssp "intermedia"
en  "Nandu"
rec "JAYRSON ARAUJO DE OLIVEIRA"
cnt "Brazil"
loc "Parque Estadual do Esphinillo Barra do Quaraí"
lat "-30.1834"
lng "-57.4501"
alt "70"
type    "adult, sex uncertain, song"
url "//www.xeno-canto.org/686584"
file    "//www.xeno-canto.org/686584/download"
file-name   "XC686584-03-11-2021 16e47 Ema BARRA.mp3"
sono    {…}
lic "//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/"
q   "A"
length  "0:09"
time    "16:47"
date    "2021-11-03"
uploaded    "2021-11-15"
also    […]
rmk ""
bird-seen   "yes"
playback-used   "no"
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? May you choose one?

Comment: Of course. Javascript is the preferred :)

Comment: Are you sure the format is correct? It doesn't look like valid JSON.

Comment: I tried copying an object from the JSON response, but it does give 500 objects as a result. This is the link to the response I copied from: https://www.xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=cnt:brazil

I assume it has something to do with the file url?

Comment: The URL does provide valid JSON. What are you finding difficult?

Comment: Only thing would actually be to retreive the .mp3 file and play it directly on the webapplication, avoiding having to use it as a static element in the project folder.

Comment: The JSON probably doesn't contain the mp3 file, instead it will be the URL

Comment: Okay, so what I understand is that it is not possible to just stream the mp3 content without completing a full download?

Comment: You might be able to stream mp3 audio, but you'll need to extract the file location from the JSON to do that. `JSON.parse` will convert the JSON into a JS object, which you can then get the URL from

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, streaming the mp3 sounds like a good idea. Do you know how to stream the mp3 audio @evolutionxbox ? Or should I just start researching?

Comment: You could use the HTML audio element and extract the URL from the JSON? https://programminghead.com/how-to-play-audio-in-html-using-javascript/ This isn't really streaming though. I'm not sure how you'd do that.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try that!